# error occured while binding gridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i've met an error that " property access must assign to the property or use its value" while binding the gridview.

here is my code.

```
cn.Open()

Dim str As String
str = "select * from Customer where cid='" & cmb_cid.SelectedValue & "' or cnm='" & cmb_cnm.SelectedValue & "'"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, cn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim ds As New Data.DataTable
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ds)
Cust_view.DataSource = ds

Cust_view.DataBindings// here is the error
cn.Close()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here `Cust_view.DataBindings`? I mean data bindings what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call DataBind method like `Cust_view.DataBind()`

`DataBindings` is a property of GirdView. We can Get the data bindings for the control using `DataBindings` property